# CSS Menu sideways or Horizontal Dropdown

Tags: html, css

I am creating a menu in CSS, when I hover over languages, I would like the it to open sideways instead of downwards.

Right its doing:

```
Languages 
  EN
  SP
  FR
```

I would like it do:

```
Languages EN SP FR
```

[Here is a CSS Deck Example](http://cssdeck.com/labs/yo9q5sia) of the below:

```css
ul.countries {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
ul li {
  font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
ul li:hover {
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
}
ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  top: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
ul li ul li {
  background: #555;
  display: inline;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
}
ul li ul li:hover {
  background: #666;
}
ul li:hover ul {
  display: inline;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<ul class="countries">
  <li>
    Languages
    <ul>
      <li>EN</li>
      <li>SP</li>
      <li>FR</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change `display:block;` to `display:inline` and delete position absolute in `ul li ul`

```
ul li ul li { 
    ....
    display: inline;           /* Changed from display:block to inline
```